# Where can I find the "Cordova Error API"?

Tags: cordova, error-handling

According to [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2016/03/09/announcing-tools-for-apache-cordova-update-7/) Microsoft blog post, "Starting with version 6.0.0, Cordova now emits error messages through a well-defined API"

Where does this definition live? The closest I could find was [this](https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/blob/master/cordova-common/src/CordovaError/CordovaError.js#L43)

I am assuming this is for the cli tool, i'm hoping to get a list of errors that can occur when using `cordova build` and `cordova platform`, without having to trawl through the cli codebase

Comment: I found this in the Cordova 6.x.x docs: `http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/6.x/reference/cordova-plugin-file/index.html#list-of-error-codes-and-meanings`

Comment: i saw that, but its for a plug in. I'm after the cordova cli "well defined" api. thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script you linked seems to be the only place where a "full definition" would exist.  Other `new CordovaError`s are thrown in the code, but so far, I've seen none that include an error code with the constructor, so those I've seen will default to `UNKNOWN_ERROR`.

I think the "well-defined API" that Microsoft's blog post might be referring to the structure of the API rather than the definition of the error codes.  In [cordova-lib/src/cordova/cordova.js](https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/blob/master/cordova-lib/src/cordova/cordova.js) it says that:

> // Each of these APIs takes a final parameter that is a callback function.
>
> // The callback is passed the error object upon failure, or undefined upon success.

So, I would guess that the criteria for "well-defined" is that Microsoft's new Visual Studio's tool can catch all the UNKNOWN_ERRORs from the API and print out the corresponding error messages, even though they don't have unique error codes.

[utils.js](https://github.com/apache/cordova-lib/blob/master/cordova-lib/src/cordova/util.js) has examples of new CordovaErrors thrown with no error codes attached.

Comment: I spent most of friday reading through the cordova source code and I have come to the same conclusion as you. Thanks for looking deeper.